# Как правильно работать с байтами в golang?

Tags: golang

Простой код:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var bs byte
    s := "hey"
    bs = []byte(s)

    fmt.Println(bs)
}
```

Выдает `./prog.go:8:7: cannot use []byte(s) (value of type []byte) as byte value in assignment`

Если сделаю вот так, то все норм:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := "hey"
    bs := []byte(s)

    fmt.Println(bs)
}
```

Как-то иначе нужно передавать byte?

У меня простая задача, нужно в функцию передать `string`, а вернуть `byte`

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, один байт или массив/слайс байтов? Если один байт, то какой именно? Если массив, то тип `byte` для этого очевидно не подходит

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, понял что объявлять нужно через []byte.
Вопрос снят.

Answer (score 1):

Извините за вопрос, на лицо ошибка в объявлении переменной.
Правильно вот так:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var bs []byte
    s := "hey"
    bs = []byte(s)

    fmt.Println(bs)
}
```